# Testing a service method with an HTTP request in Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, karma-jasmine

I am having an issue with one of my unit tests whereas a function that contains an HTTP post request is not returning a string when it should be. Here is the service function in question:

```
public getAnonToken(prev?: string): string {
        if (this.tokens[prev]) {
            return this.tokens[prev]
        }

        if(prev) {
            this.tokens[prev] = prev;
        }        

        this.http.post<any>(HttpUrl.ANON_TOKEN, {})
            .subscribe((response) => {
                this.saveAuthToken(response.data);
                this.tokens[prev] = response.data;

                // analytics!!!
                // Global.internalAnalytics.getAnonToken();
                return response.data;
            });            
    }
```

As you can see, a request made to the token generation endpoint which returns an observable which I then subscribe to and return the token from the getAnonToken() function.

Here is my test:`

```
fit("should call the token endpoint and save then return a new token if old token has expired", () => {
    const mockTokenResponseData = {
        data: "i am a token"         
    }
    spyOn(httpClient, "post").and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockTokenResponseData));

    expect(authService.getAnonToken()).toEqual("i am a token");        

});`
```

As you can see, I am creating a mock response (an observable) and then setting it as the return value when the post request is made using a spy. Instead of 'i am a token' I get undefined. I have a feeling this is because the test is not waiting for the observable to return but I am unsure as to how this is resolved. Can anyone see what is happening here?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing returning the `this.http.post` in your function, also, you need to put your `expect` into the `subscription`.

Return the call to `http.post`

```
return this.http.post<any>(HttpUrl.ANON_TOKEN, {})
    .subscribe((response) => {
        this.saveAuthToken(response.data);
        this.tokens[prev] = response.data;

        // analytics!!!
        // Global.internalAnalytics.getAnonToken();
        return response.data;
    });
```

Please, not the `return` in front of `this.http.post`

Put the `expect` inside the `subscription`

```
authService.getAnonToken().subscribe((data) => {
    expect(data).toEqual("i am a token");
});
```

Hope it helps